# Javascript: generalizing react-loadable with closure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, es6-promise, react-loadable

I am using react-loadable to load the views. The code below works fine:

```
const Home = Loadable({
    loader: () =>
        import ('./views/home'),
    loading: Loading,
});
```

But I have multiple views, hence I want to generalize (refactor) the above code by replacing the path string with a variable. **And that's where the problem starts.** I tried following technique, but it doesn't load the target view, instead it just keeps the **Loading** view, which is just a temporary view containing simply 'Loading...' string.

```
const getLoadableView = (viewPath) => {
  return Loadable({
    loader: ((p) => {
      const m = p;
      return () => {
        console.log(m); //this one prints the correct value
        return import(m);
      };
    })(viewPath),
    loading: Loading
  });
}
const Home = getLoadableView('./views/home');
```

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Is `getLoadableView` declared in the same place (module) that `Home` is created in?

Comment: You really need neither `m`, nor `p`, nor that IIFE. Just use `viewPath`.

Comment: Yes, both are declared in same place. I tried without local variables too, but no luck. Can you come up with an example?

Comment: Try `.catch()`ing errors from the import. Also, in what environment are you running this? Do you use a transpiler and/or bundler? Does it support dynamic imports?

Comment: The error it throws is: Cannot find module './views/home'. Where as if replace variable m in import call with the './views/home', it again works....
So, there is something weird happening in import call.

Comment: Again, do you use a transpiler/bundler?

Comment: Yes, it is react-scripts, which uses webpack at it's core...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by the following trick:

```
const getLoadableView = (viewPath) => {
  return Loadable({
    loader: () => import(`./${viewPath}`);;
    })(viewPath),
    loading: Loading
  });
}
const homeViewPath = 'views/home';
const Home = getLoadableView(homeViewPath);
```

You can notice that I have done nothing special, but just partitioned the path in two parts. The first path is hardcoded in import call.

Obviously this is not a solid solution, but I could not find the actual reason behind such behaviour of import call.